# Определение "глубокомысленный" можно ли применить к человеку?

Tags: выбор-слов

**[Глубокомысленный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)**

1. *книжн.* полный серьезных, значительных и сложных по содержанию мыслей ◆ *Глубокомысленное сочинение. Необычайно **глубокомысленный человек.***
2. серьезный, сосредоточенный ◆ *Он шутит с самым глубокомысленным видом.*

> Окрылённая блистательно сыгранной ролью глубокомысленной и несколько
> пресыщенной звезды...

***Глубокомысленная звезда*** меня смущает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так изредка говорят и о человеке, но стилистически это *небезупречно*: "глубокомысл**енным**" (имеющим **косвенное** отношение к процессу мышления) бывает действие человека, его вид или взгляд (как результат того, что человек глубокомысл**енно** взглянул) и т. п. Сам же человек мыслит **напрямую**, а не *косвенно*; это **его** мысль (а не чья-то пролетающая по ходу его движения), и он - "мысл**ящий**" (глубоко или не очень).

Answer (score 3):

Меня тоже смущает это словосочетание. Понимаю, что автор хотел сказать, что юная актриса успешно справилась с серьёзной ролью блистательной звезды. А вот глубокомысленной - это мудрой, способной мыслить, глубокой.Тем более рядом с определением "пресыщенной", нет ли здесь разнородности понятий? Глубокомыслие как качество личности – способность глубоко проникать в сущность явлений; отличаться глубиной, значительностью и сложностью мыслей, суждений, принципов, взглядов, а пресыщенность ближе к скуке.

Как-то к звезде глубокомысленность не подходит, больше к человеку как личности, а не к профессии артиста-звезды. Артист может быть выдающимся, талантливым и т.д. К звезде трудно подобрать другой эпитет, кроме "блистательная". Может, предложить вариант замены эпитетов:

Окрылённая блестяще (успешно, талантливо) сыгранной ролью блистательной и несколько пресыщенной звезды...

Answer (score 2):

Окрылённая блистательно сыгранной ролью **глубокомыслящей** и несколько пресыщенной звезды...

Синонимы к "глубокомысленный": серьёзный, сложный; философичный, философский, мыслящий, вдумчивый, озабоченный, сосредоточенный, думающий.

Глубокомыслящий человек – не поверхностный, способный высказать оригинальную точку зрения. Такое впечатление можно получить при недолгом общении. В то же время в этом слове есть доля иронии – это же всё-таки роль, а не сам герой.

Answer (score 0):

> Определение “глубокомысленный” можно ли применить к человеку?

Вполне, но вопрос-то, судя по всему, не в этом.

> Глубокомысленная звезда меня смущает...

Правильно смущает. Только причина, видимо, другая. Автор, похоже, не разобрался со смыслом слова "звезда". Конечно, же звезда, как и всякий представитель рода человеческого, может быть глубокомысленной. Но здесь-то явно не та характеристика подразумевалась. **"Ушедшей в себя", "скрытной", "уединенной" даже "взбалмошной"** - скорее всего что-то из этого ряда, хотя точного значения тут не угадаешь, конечно.

А если автор реально имел в виду этакого "гиганта мысли", он очень неудачно выразился, ибо совершенно инородно в таком контексте.

Comment: Автор вполне разобрался со смыслом. Юную актрису приглашают на роль в заграницы. Она очень старается не ударить в грязь лицом, хотя трусит отчаянно. Исходя из этого моего пояснения можно не трогать "глубокомысленную звезду"?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova нет не думаю, что можно, не подходит по смыслу в этот контекст. Это у Бендера Киса мог "многозначительно  надувать щеки", чтобы казаться глубокомысленным, а певичка-то это разве с такой ролью свыклась? С ролью мыслителя? Все-таки автор не прав. Но если я ошибаюсь, то оставляете конечно, но у читателя возникает масса вопросов.